# Как распределить маршруты по дням в месяце?

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм, динамические-массивы, сложность

нужна помощь с распределением маршрутов по дням месяца.

Ситуация такая. Есть к примеру **3 зоны**, в каждой зоне есть маршруты(не всегда равное количество).
Задача распределить маршруты по рабочим дням в месяце, но есть условие: маршруты из двух зон **НЕ** могут быть назначены на один день, **т.е. зоны не должны пересекаться**.

**Пример:**

**Маршруты 1 зоны:** *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43;*

**Маршруты 2 зоны:** *44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79;*

**Маршруты 3 зоны:** *80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120;*

Получается 120 маршрутов (к примеру) на месяц. Допустим в месяце 20 дней, соответственно 120 делим на 20 получаем 6 маршрутов в день.
По итогу мы должны получить распределение маршрутов по рабочим дням недели в таком виде:
1-6,7-12,13-18,19-24,25-30,31-36,37-43,44-49,50-55,56-61,62-67,68-73,74-79,80-85,86-91,92-97,98-103,104-109,110-115,116-120

Как понятно по количеству блоков "номер-номер"(с какого маршрута по какой) это распределено на 20 дней.
Так же видно, что маршруты не пересекаются зонами, т.е. в 1 день нету например такого:
"43-49", потому что маршрут 43 из 1й зоны, а остальные из 2й.

По итогу я начал писать алгоритм, чтобы это все распределять и ничего лучше не придумал (пока что) как создать двумерный массив, т.е. массив в котором есть массивы с зонами, эти массивы имеют номера маршрутов.
Далее написал функцию, которая распределяет эти маршруты, не перемешивая их между зонами путём рекурсии и создания **ТРЕХмерного** массива.

После чего я вывожу первый и последний элемент каждого массива и получается к примеру строка:
*'1-6,7-12,13-18,19-24,25-30,31-36,37-43,44-49,50-55,56-61,62-67,68-73,74-79,80-85,86-91,92-97,98-103,104-109,110-115,116-120'*;

**P.S.** пришлось немного фиксить, потому что было и так, что в зависимости от количества рабочих дней в неделе маршрутов могло быть 1 в день, что плохо, поэтому я дописал фичу, которая перебирает массив массивов и если длина вложенного менее или равна трём (количество маршрутов менее или равно 3м), то засовываем в предыдущий день (как бы)

**По идее все работает, но есть огромное НО.** Оно работает не всегда адекватно из-за различного количества рабочих дней в месяце. **Например:** В месяце 22 рабочих дня, а алгоритм разделяет все в итоге на 19 блоков, что соответствует 19ти дням, или если 17 рабочих дней, то делит на 21 блок, что равно 21му дню (НО ЭТО ТОЛЬКО ПРИМЕР, реальные цифры можно увидеть при тесте моего кода).

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне поправить код, чтобы количество распределенных блоков было строго равно числу рабочих дней (не зависело от количества рабочих дней)?

```js
// Массив a - маршруты
const a = [
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43],
[44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
[80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120]
];
const days = 20;
const countRoutsInDay = Math.floor(a.flat().length / days);
const newArr = [];
const resultArr = [];
let str = '';

//Разделяем на массивы по дням
const splitterRouts = (count) => {
  let arr = [];
  let currentElemOfMainArray = count;
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(a[count].length / countRoutsInDay); i++) {
    arr[i] = a[count].slice((i * countRoutsInDay), (i * countRoutsInDay) + countRoutsInDay);

    if (i === Math.ceil(a[count].length / countRoutsInDay) - 1) {
      currentElemOfMainArray += 1;
      newArr.push(arr);
      if (currentElemOfMainArray < a.length) {
        splitterRouts(currentElemOfMainArray);
      }
    }
  }
}

splitterRouts(0);

// Если маршрутов меньше или равно 3, то соединить в предыдущий день
newArr.forEach((el) => {
  el.forEach((el2) => {
    if (el2.length <= 3) {
      const summRoute = el[el.length - 2].concat(el[el.length - 1]);
      el.splice(el.indexOf(el[el.length - 2]), el.indexOf(el[el.length - 1]), summRoute);
    }
  })
});

newArr.forEach((el) => {
  el.forEach((el2) => {
    str += `${el2[0]}-${el2[el2.length - 1]},`
    resultArr.push(str.split(','));
  })
})

console.log(str);
console.log(resultArr.length - 1); // данный результат должен быть равен количеству дней заданных выше
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы второй раз задаёте вопрос, но задача по-прежнему плохо поставлена, потому и нет реакции.

Пусть `z[]` - список с количеством маршрутов в каждой зоне, `n` - общее количество, `md` - рабочих дней в месяце. Сначала распределим зоны по дням целочисленным делением.

```
d[i], r[i] = md*z[i] / n, md*z[i] & n
```

Если (пока) сумма дней меньше `md`, увеличиваем на единицу `d[i]` с наибольшим остатком (`r[i]`)

Теперь нужно каждое `z[i]` равномерно разделить на количество дней `d[i]`. В каждый из дней будет `z[i] / d[i]` маршрутов, и из них в `z[i] & d[i]` дней добавить по одному маршруту. Можно в первые дни, можно случайно распределить, (а можно и сразу алгоритмом Брезенхема распределить всё).